# Non-conformable arguments stop function that uses matices as inputs from working

Tags: r

Im trying to replicate the code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qg_rDs1PYUZSWmApJEkDZPUS-avXxbhp-63dkQgxjAk/edit) for "R code for replicating kings". Below I attach the code up to the point it works fine.AFter this point I get `Error in istate %*% Pmat : non-conformable arguments`. Why does this happen? Do I miss something. Maybe someone can figure it out. That all I have no other dataset or something. I tried to run the example that is int doc as well but get the same error.

```
MMod<-function (Pmat, cycle, n, Init, halfcycle=F, measure, discount=.03)
{cumul<-0 
i<-1 
istate<-Init 
m<-measure*cycle
if (halfcycle) {cumul<-0.5*(Init%*%m)} 
while (i <= n)
{ istate<-istate%*%Pmat   
imeasure<-istate%*%m   
cumul<-cumul+imeasure
#print(paste(c(i,round(istate,2),cumul)))   i<-i+1
m<-m*(1-discount*cycle)
}
if (halfcycle) {cumul<-cumul - 0.5*imeasure} 
return(cumul)} 

MToll<-function (Pmat, cycle, n, Init, toll, discount=.03)
{cumul<-0 
i<-1 
m<-1 
istate<-Init 
nstates<-length(Init)
LTM<-matrix(0, nrow=nstates, ncol=nstates)
LTM[lower.tri(LTM)]<-1 
while (i <= n)
{
  istate2<-istate%*%Pmat 
  netshifts<-LTM%*%t(istate-istate2) 
  tolli<-netshifts[-1]%*%toll*m 
  cumul<-cumul+tolli 
  istate<-istate2 
  m<-m*(1-discount*cycle) 
  i<-i+1 }
return(cumul)
}

MST<-function (Pmat, n, Init)
{i<-1 
istate<-Init 
States<-Init 
while (i <= n)
{
  istate<-c(istate%*%Pmat) 
  States<-cbind(States, istate) 
  i<-i+1 }
return(States)}



New.calc<-function(P1, P2, HSU, cost.Treat, cost.Care, Toll, Fixed.Treat, halfcycle=T,...) {
  QY1<-MMod(Pmat=P1,measure=HSU,halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  QY2<-MMod(Pmat=P2,measure=HSU,halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  Treat1<-MMod(Pmat=P1,measure=cost.Treat[,1],halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  Treat2<-MMod(Pmat=P2,measure=cost.Treat[,2],halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  Care1<-MMod(Pmat=P1,measure=cost.Care,halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  Care2<-MMod(Pmat=P2,measure=cost.Care,halfcycle=halfcycle,...)
  Toll1<-MToll(Pmat=P1,toll=Toll,...)   
  Toll2<-MToll(Pmat=P2,toll=Toll,...)   
  ansDF<-data.frame( Utility=c(QY1, QY2), 
                                                                                                 Treatment=c(Treat1+Fixed.Treat[1], Treat2+Fixed.Treat[2]), 
                                                                                                 RC=c(Care1, Care2),                    TC=c(Toll1, Toll2))
  ansDF<-data.frame(ansDF, Total_Cost=apply(ansDF[,2:4], 1, sum))   
  ansDF2<-rbind(ansDF, ansDF[2,]-ansDF[1,])   rownames(ansDF2)<-c("Tr1", "Tr2", "Diff")
  ans1<-(Care2-Care1+Treat2-Treat1+Toll2-Toll1+Fixed.Treat[2]-Fixed.Treat[1])   ans2<-(QY2-QY1)
  return(list(Cost_Utility=ansDF2, ICUR=ans1/ans2))
}



P.RILUneg<-read.table(text="
6.8604466e-01 0.27237339416 0.0392288844 0.0020896625 0.00011414761 0.00014925021 2.6080360e-02 0.74183221490 0.2130311396 0.0167613306 0.00121619371 0.00107876162 7.9577302e-04 0.04513125922 0.8115775903 0.1232709064 0.01337414561 0.00585032537 2.7391412e-05 0.00229455178 0.0796554694 0.7391659905 0.16375225528 0.01510434163
8.9680288e-07 0.00009978931 0.0051797995 0.0981474867 0.79583386882 0.10073815882
0.0000000e+00 0.00000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.00000000000 1.00000000000",fill = TRUE , header = FALSE ) 
P.RILUpos<-read.table(text="
6.9449942e-01 0.27189897910 0.0314651341 0.0019380647 8.9161464e-05 0.00010923903 2.6903100e-02 0.77862279416 0.1766404706 0.0160845681 9.8349868e-04 0.00076556815 8.0656346e-04 0.04576193898 0.7942333863 0.1423245490 1.3101929e-02 0.00377163306 2.7854076e-05 0.00233633511 0.0797978780 0.7588375567 1.4166520e-01 0.01733517825
9.1518056e-07 0.00010202547 0.0052463334 0.1011747832 8.2156998e-01 0.07190595839
0.0000000e+00 0.00000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000e+00 1.00000000000",fill = TRUE , header = FALSE ) 
P.RILUneg<-as.matrix(P.RILUneg)
P.RILUpos<-as.matrix(P.RILUpos)

Q.stages<-c(0.7886603, 0.7425028, 0.6293351, 0.5407166, 0.4644944, 0) 

RC.med<-c(0, 14784, 21696, 29568, 40200, 0)
RC.informal<-c(0, 15588, 30336, 39876, 49428, 36372) 
RC.soc<-c(0, 30372, 52032, 69444, 89628, 36372) 

TC.med<-c(245.5 ,5036.5,11082.5,17203.0,10911.5)
TC.soc<-c(245.5 ,5036.5,13633.5,22305.0,20462.5) 
COST.RILU<-matrix(c(rep(0, 7), rep(158*12, 4), 0), nrow=6)
COST.RILU.fixed<-c(0, 184)




New.calc(P.RILUneg, P.RILUpos, HSU=Q.stages, cost.Treat=COST.RILU, cost.Care=RC.med, 
         Toll=TC.med, Fixed.Treat = COST.RILU.fixed, Init=c(0,1,0,0,0,0), cycle=1/12, n=60)
```